# Correct Use Of Schema For UK Business Address

Tags: schema, local

Whats the correct use of schema for local business address, there doesn't seem to be a facility for town, city and county?? In the example below I would use addressRegion twice but I'm thinking its wrong to use twice?

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
              <span itemprop="name">Company Name</span>
              <span itemprop="streetAddress">Some Road Name</span>
              <span itemprop="addressLocality">Town</span>
              <span itemprop="addressRegion">City</span>
              <span itemprop="addressRegion">County</span>
              <span itemprop="postalCode">Postcode</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking into this right now.

The "county" is an obselete bit of UK postal addresses. As one tedious example, an address in Bristol has no county at all, since it's a unitary authority.

addressRegion is given in the example documents as the state, i.e "CA". My suspicion therefore is that it ought to look like

```
streetAddress = 12 Acacia Avenue, Town
addressLocality = Bristol
addressRegion = England
postalCode = BS1 1AA
```

...but I wonder where would be a sensible place to ask?